# What books are good to study Solid Mensuration?

Tags: geometry

Preferably I want those that contain the following topics:

Solid Figures

```
Polyhedrons
Prisms
Pyramids
Prismatoid
Truncated Prisms
Cylinders
Cones
Spheres
```

I've been able to find good references for Plane Geometry. But for solid geometry, it feels so limited. I cannot find a comprehensive reference that really deals with all kinds of 3D figures and is made in a modern way with detailed explanations, flow and illustrations.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for self-study, I recommend this book:

[https://www.amazon.com/Solid-Geometry-310-M-Welchons/dp/B001CZ0V88](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001CZ0V88)

It is modern in terms of language (I can read books from the 1940s without effort).  And there is about 1 illustration per page (small pages).  In addition, it's a thorough treatment.  And is addressed to students, not practitioners (i.e. is accessible).

I don't have an in print recommendation, if you need to purchase several for a classroom.  (But I'm sure there are products sold, which you could research by contacting local textbook sales reps.)

Comment: Does it have those 3D figures in detail? Just asking and thank you.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "in detail".  I find the figures effective, since they are so frequent.  They are about half line drawings, half shaded.  All black and white.

Comment: I mean if they discuss different quantities such as surface area and volume and have different situations such as in prisms where truncated prisms are also discussed.

Comment: It's got a whole chapter on prisms and cylinders (mostly prisms).  About 30 pages.  Right prisms, truncated, congruency, inscribed and circumscribed, etc.  Several sections of exercises (with all answers in the back).  It's a good, classical treatment of solid geometry for students who have not had analytic geometry or calculus yet.